# Overlapping Legends on Angular-Chart's Piechart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am using angular-charts (in a bid to simplify my life when it comes to displaying charts and stuff). So far, [it had been pretty straightforward](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#getting_started) and I was able to render my piechart perfectly fine.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true">
</canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
  $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});
```

However, now that I try to include the chart's legends, I have run into an issue; my legend labels are overlapping and I am not sure how to solve it (if there is indeed a workaround?!). Would greatly appreciate any help on this, :)

**UPDATE:**

```
.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6
  .panel.panel-primary(ng-controller='pieChartController')
    .panel-heading
      h2.panel-title Title
    .panel-body
      canvas#pie.chart.chart-pie(chart-data='data', chart-labels='labels', chart-legend='true', chart-options='options')
```

**UPDATE:**

Upon inspection of my pie chart's legends, I find that it is subjected to the following CSS rules:

```
.chart-legend,
.bar-legend,
.line-legend,
.pie-legend,
.radar-legend,
.polararea-legend,
.doughnut-legend {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /* NOTE: Browsers automatically add 40px of padding-left to all lists, so we should offset that, otherwise the legend is off-center */
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  /* Webkit */
  -moz-padding-start: 0;
  /* Mozilla */
  padding-left: 0;
  /* IE (handles all cases, really, but we should also include the vendor-specific properties just to be safe) */
}
```

in angular-chart.css.

```
ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

in bootstrap.css.

```
.chart-legend li,
.bar-legend li,
.line-legend li,
.pie-legend li,
.radar-legend li,
.polararea-legend li,
.doughnut-legend li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 28px;
  font-size: smaller;
  cursor: default;
}
```

in angular-chart.js.

Comment: Do you have any CSS that could be messing with the legend? I don't see it happening: http://run.plnkr.co/fXrOhjVNKTvG44xC/

Comment: @J.Titus I am unable to view your plunkr: `{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "Preview has expired or project does not exist."`
}. What are some examples of interfering CSS? I ask because I believe that I do not, but well, I could be wrong.

Comment: Try this link? http://plnkr.co/edit/w8jB0B125DfNxIR1QjCT?p=preview

Comment: @J.Titus Indeed, the labels do not overlap; however, my issue persists.

Comment: Do you have any CSS involving `<ul>`s or `<li>`s?

Comment: @J.Titus I am using bootstrap and my pie chart is currently stuck in a panel. I will update my question to include this new info.

Comment: @J.Titus I am using Jade.

Comment: Strange. I updated the Plunker with the new information, but still don't see the same problem you're having. Sorry :(

Comment: @J.Titus I have checked the my chart's legends to see the CSS rules they are subjected to. There does not appear to be any interfering CSS... Will update post to include this information as well. Very confused here.

Comment: The only way I'm able to force the legend elements to overlap (not with each other, just with the colors) is by cancelling out the `padding` on `.pie-legend li`. Don't know what else it could be. Good luck.

Comment: @J.Titus I have just found something extremely odd... I was inspecting the elements on your Plunkr in hopes of finding a clue as to what's different. I found this: `<span style="background-color:rgba(151,187,205,1)"></span> Download sales`. On mine, it'd have been `<span style="background-color:rgba(151,187,205,1)">Download sales</span>`. Any idea how I could circumvent this?!

Comment: @J.Titus Once I moved my `span` text out of the `span`. It works perfect... :(

Comment: @J.Titus And no, I did not mess around with the default legendTemplate. I don't understand why this is happening :(

Comment: Wow. Different version of Angular-Chart maybe?

Comment: @J.Titus I have only added angular-chart last Friday!!! OMG!!! :( Looks like you are using V0.8.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For future reference, in case anyone runs into the same odd problem as me, ...**

I have checked and double-checked and can confirm that I was indeed using the latest versions of `Chart.js` and `angular-chart.js` (which @J.Titus was also using in his Plunkr).

```
"chart.js": "^1.0.2"
"angular-chart.js": "~0.8.8"
```

Yet, strangely, I found something really odd.

I was inspecting the elements on your Plunkr in hopes of finding a clue as to what's different. I found this on @J.Titus' Plunkr:

`<span style="background-color:rgba(151,187,205,1)"></span> Download sales`

On mine, it was:

`<span style="background-color:rgba(151,187,205,1)">Download sales</span>`

In order to correct this, I delved into `Chart.js` and changed all occurrences of `legendTemplate` (`ctrl + F` is your best friend!) to the following:

`"<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"`

This moves the label text out of the `<span>` tag, effectively resolving the overlap issue.

Comment: @J.Titus Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured out the issue :)